# Webpacker compilation failed - ERROR: [Errno 21] Is a directory: 'bin'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

I just started playing around with Docker everything is cruising along until I tried to access a page of my super basic app. I got this:

```
web_1    | [Webpacker] Compiling...
web_1    | [Webpacker] Compilation failed:
web_1    | ERROR: [Errno 21] Is a directory: 'bin'
web_1    | CRITICAL:root:Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1    |   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cliapp/app.py", line 182, in _run
web_1    |     self.settings.load_configs()
web_1    |   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cliapp/settings.py", line 829, in load_configs
web_1    |     self._read_ini(pathname, f)
web_1    |   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cliapp/settings.py", line 838, in _read_ini
web_1    |     cp.readfp(f)
web_1    |   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 324, in readfp
web_1    |     self._read(fp, filename)
web_1    |   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 512, in _read
web_1    |     raise MissingSectionHeaderError(fpname, lineno, line)
web_1    | MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.
web_1    | file: /usr/src/app/config/webpack/development.js, line: 1
web_1    | "process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'\n"
web_1    | 
web_1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1    |   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cliapp/app.py", line 182, in _run
web_1    |     self.settings.load_configs()
web_1    |   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cliapp/settings.py", line 829, in load_configs
web_1    |     self._read_ini(pathname, f)
web_1    |   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cliapp/settings.py", line 838, in _read_ini
web_1    |     cp.readfp(f)
web_1    |   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 324, in readfp
web_1    |     self._read(fp, filename)
web_1    |   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 512, in _read
web_1    |     raise MissingSectionHeaderError(fpname, lineno, line)
web_1    | MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.
web_1    | file: /usr/src/app/config/webpack/development.js, line: 1
web_1    | "process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'\n"
```

This is the first time I've seen this error.

Here's my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

services:

  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
```

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.6                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

LABEL maintainer="ejvalmores@gmail.com"

RUN apt-get update -yqq && apt-get install -yqq --no-install-recommends \
nodejs

RUN apt-get install -yqq yarn

COPY Gemfile* /usr/src/app/
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN bundle install

COPY . /usr/src/app

CMD ["bin/rails", "s", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

And here's my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'                                                                                                                                                                                                         
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.5'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.2', '>= 6.0.2.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem 'redis'
```

Anyone encountered this error? Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I got the same error. Maybe you need to install the latest version of nodejs and yarn.

Add this to your Dockerfile:

(assuming you have curl, if not install it)

```
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x  | bash -
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add
RUN echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs yarn
```

And then at the end I add the following to compile:

```
RUN npm rebuild node-sass #maybe you don't need it, I do
RUN bundle exec rails assets:precompile
```

Also a source where I found most of this information: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/7329

Comment: The `bundle exec rails assets:precompile` command saved my day, thanks a lot.